# How to drag map under markers and pin them in ionic 2?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic2

in this code I'am trying to make something like `Uber` map section to pin and stop markers. but i am dragging maker instead of map under marker.
It is not looking good user experiences.
I want to add target marker after setting Location and tapping on Originmaker 
and then binding them in a view.

```
    initializeMap() {

    let image = 'assets/img/taxi3.png';
    let minZoomLevel = 16;
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    zoom: minZoomLevel,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
            trafficLayer.setMap(this.map);
            this.OriginMarker();
      });
    }

OriginMarker(){   
   let image = 'assets/img/Untitled-1.png';   
   let marker = new google.maps.Marker({    
    map: this.map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: this.map.getCenter(),
    draggable: true,
     icon: image
  });
}

TargetMarker() {  

    let image = 'assets/img/Untitled-2.png';
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     map: this.map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: this.map.getCenter(),
    draggable: true,
     icon: image
  }); 
}
```